# How to adjust the column width when showed in Chrome using window.print()?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my project, I have to print the web page and I'm able to do that with windows.print() js function but. Column width is completely different from web page when the preview shows in chrome browser/IE browsers.

Actual web page is below
[image: Webpage looks like this]

Then when I print this using window.print() it looks like this.(Column width is totally messed up). Refer below.
[image: Print preview in chrome browser]

Please help me on fixing this. tried the @media print option and not working at all.

Comment: print != web. It will be very hard to get this completely right. That being said, show us your (CSS) code and what you tried.

Comment: .minWidth {
        width:5% !important;
    }
    .minQWidth {
        width:2% !important;
    }

    @@media print{
        .minWidth {
            width:5%;
            max-width:5% !important;
        }
        .minQWidth {
            width:2%;
            max-width:2% !important;
        }
    } here .minwidth class is identifier for last 2 columns and minqwidth clss is identifier for 1st column

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the post itself, not into comments.